# Application backend and networking?

Tags: database, networking

I'm not sure if the title I used is good, but hopefully my question will be better.

I have an java application that tracks data on PennyAuction sites(such as beezid.com), and will eventually upload all of the data to a database. Clients will download a java application and run it on their local machine, but this local machine application will have to be able to access the database and obtain all of the data.

All I have ever done is java applications programming, so this is all very new to me. Can anybody help me with a solution that will be able to accomplish this?

This is all I can think of:

1. Server that will run Backend application 24/7, and use JDBC to upload data to database.
2. Separate server for database alone.

I have no idea how the client application should connect to the database though.

Any help/links to tutorials on stuff like this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could actually let your clients connect to the database directly if the database is on a public IP.

An architecurally much better way of doing this is with webservices. This would make your system much more safe, robust and scalable.

Web services are client and server applications that communicate over the World Wide Web’s (WWW) HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP). As described by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C), web services provide a standard means of interoperating between software applications running on a variety of platforms and frameworks. Web services are characterized by their great interoperability and extensibility, as well as their machine-processable descriptions, thanks to the use of XML. Web services can be combined in a loosely coupled way to achieve complex operations. Programs providing simple services can interact with each other to deliver sophisticated added-value services.